# Why javascript is not catching event from onClick function?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

So I have html rendered by ColdFusion backend, dynamically created  tags which have an id as well onClick attribute... However in JavaScript when I try to console.log(event), it returns undefined, when I inspect the window, everything populates including the id and value. Do you know of any reason it could be happening? Would really appreciate it.

Here is my ColdFusion backend script

```
  PID==""?SelectedVal1='Selected':SelectedVal1='' 

  writeOutput('<OPTION value="" #SelectedVal1#>-- All Programs --</OPTION>');
  for (row in getPrograms) {
    listfind(pid,getPrograms.ProgramID)?SelectedVal2='Selected':SelectedVal2=''
    if (getPrograms.ProgramID!=18){
      writeOutput('<OPTION onClick="addProgramToList();" id="#getPrograms.ProgramShortName#" value="#getPrograms.ProgramID#" #SelectedVal2#>#getPrograms.ProgramShortName#</OPTION>');
    }
  }
```

Here is the JS function

```
addProgramToList = (event) => {
    //arrayOfPrograms.push(e);
    console.log(event)
  }
```

Comment: That's a feature of the inline event handlers (the script in the value of the attribute is executed, and yours doesn't pass the argument to the invoked function). You have to pass `event` object from the function call, i.e. `onClick="addProgramToList(event);"`.

Comment: Additionally, usually listening clicks on the options is not useful, rather listen `onchange` on the select element. Also, you could [make your life easier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically created Javascript you need to consider event delegation. If using JQuery is would look something like

```
$( "#someExistingElement" ).on( "click", "##targetElementID#", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First up all we should not use onClick event in option tag. And If you use onClick event in Select tag it will be calling a method twice instead of one time. So better can use onChange event in select tag.

Please verify below code and it will be helping to solve your issue.

***My Sample Code***

```js
addProgramToList = (event) => {
 console.log(event);
}
```

```html
<select name="select" onclick="return addProgramToList(event);">
  <option value="">Select All</option>
  <option value="1">Bhagathsingh Sekar</option>
  <option value="2">Arun A</option>
  <option value="3">Nelson G Jayaraj</option>
</select>
```